# How to show that $k \cdot |I| \le |\cup_{i \in I} X_i|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ${\cal X} = (X_1,...,X_n)$ be a family of subsets of a set $S$ and let $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. I know that

$$k \cdot ( \min_{I' \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} \{n - |I'| + |\bigcup_{i \in I'}X_i|\} - \min_{I' \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} \{n - |I'| + |\bigcup_{i \in I'} X_i \cap (S - \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i)|\}) \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$.

How I can to show that $k \cdot |I| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$?

Comment: In the second term there is a double union over $i \in I'$ and $i \in I$. Is this a typo? They should not share the same index $i$.

Comment: I change the question. The $I'$ match the set that minimize each min. Moreover, $I$ match at $I$ of "for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$".